# Basic Laravel4 yield not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Recently began learning laravel4 and i am experimenting with blade templates. For some reason these was working but all of a sudden they have stopped working and when i go to view the site with said template on it just shows the @yield directive and not displaying the section its meant to be .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehMBK.png <-- screenshot of source when viewed in browser

This is all the code i am using currently this is dead basic stuff

app/routes.php

```
//set base route
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

app/controllers/HomeController

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

protected $layout = 'base';

public function index()
{

    $data = array(
        'heading' => 'Hello Laravel (from Home)',
        'body' => 'This is awesome, from the HomeController'
    );

    $this->layout->content = View::make('test', $data);
}

}
```

app/views/base.php (html layout template)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app/views/test.blade.php

```
@section('content')
<h1>{{ $heading }}</h1>
<p>{{ $body }}</p>
@stop
```

Thats pretty much it i have no idea why its not showing up when i view the site. This did work and then for some reason stopped and i have no idea why. I have even tried a fresh install of laravel with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add @extends to your test.blade.php and rename your base.php to base.blade.php.

```
@extends('base')
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply and yes just adding the blade.php to the base file worked. Feel kind of stupid. Thanks for the response!